# Copying the content of one page to another in the same worksheet of an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on VBA excel file, where I'm supposed to fix an error.
There are two worksheets "Feasibility" and "RFQ Info" in the excel file I'm working. There is a code written in VBA which copies some data from the "RFQ Info" to the "Feasibility" worksheet after compiling it with the help of compile button.
The problem is that everytime I compile, the first page created in Feasibility worksheet is copied over other pages in the same worksheet

```
Sub Create_Table_TF()
      
    Dim Rng As Range, Rw As Integer, i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = Sheets("Feasibility").Range("A1:Z60") 'Change range to suit
    For Rw = 1 To Range("AA5")
    Rng.Copy Rng.Offset(Rng.Rows.Count)
    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(Rng.Rows.Count)
    Next Rw
    
    i = Range("AA5")
    If Sheets("Feasibility").Range("AA5") <> "" Then
    
    Sheets("Feasibility").Rows((i + 1) * 60 + 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

What can I add to avoid this overwriting or copying the data of one sheet to another. Please help.Thank you in advance.